# two divs one below another (one grid one flex)

Tags: html, css

I need to align the divs one below another.

Here is working demo https://jsfiddle.net/h8gfr9nt/2/

What I want to achieve is for the `scores` div to be below the other `game` div.
Which means to be arranged under each other.

I don't have much experience so I need your help.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the fact one element has a `grid` layout and the other has a `flex` layout, it's because you've applied `position: absolute` on the `.game`-element. In this case, is it necessary to apply `position: absolute`?

Comment: Yes need to be `absolute`

Comment: Is [this](https://i.imgur.com/6R7924B.png) what you want to achieve?  I just add border in your `.game` and `.scores` to see how it look likes.